# execute a PHP method every X seconds?

Tags: php, websocket, daemon

**Context :**

I'm making a PHP websocket server ([here](https://github.com/wmcmurray/websocket-framework)) running as a DAEMON in which there is obviously a main loop listening for sockets connections and incoming data so i can't just create an other loop with a `sleep(x_number_of_seconds);` in it because it'll freeze my whole server.

I can't execute an external script with a CRON job or fork a new process too (i guess) because I have to be in the scope of my server class to send data to connected client sockets.

Does anyone knows a magic trick to achieve this in PHP ? :/

**Some crazy ideas :**

1. Keeping track of the last loop execution time with `microtime(true)`, and compare it with the current time on each loop, if it's about my desired X seconds interval, execute the method... which would result in a very drunk and inconsistent interval loop.
2. Run a JavaScript `setInterval()` in a browser that will communicate with my server trough a websocket and tell it to execute my method... i said they where crazy ideas !

**Additional infos about what i'm trying to achieve :**

I'm making a little online game (RPG like) in which I would like to add some NPCs that updates their behaviours every X seconds.

Is there an other ways of achieving this ? Am I missing something ? Should I rewrite my server in Node.js ??

Thanks a lot for the help !

Comment: #1 + a small timeout for select() is how you do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A perfect alternative doesn't seams to exists so I'll use my crazy solution #1 :

```
$this->last_tick_time = microtime(true);
$this->tick_interval = 1;
$this->tick_counter = 0;

while(true)
{
    //loop code here...

    $t= microtime(true) - $this->last_tick_time;

    if($t>= $this->tick_interval)
    {
        $this->on_server_tick(++$this->tick_counter);
        $this->last_tick_time = microtime(true) - ($t- $this->tick_interval);
    }
}
```

Basically, if the time elapsed since the last server tick is greater or equal to my desired tick interval, execute `on_server_tick()` method. **And most importantly :** we subtract the time overflow to make the next tick happen faster if this one happened too late. This way we fill the gaps and at the end, if the `socket_select` timeout is set to 1 second, we will never have a gap greater than 1.99999999+ second.

I also keep track of the tick counter, this way I can use modulo (%) to **execute code on multiple intervals** like this :

```
protected function on_server_tick($counter)
{
    if($counter%5 == 0)
    {
        // 5 seconds interval
    }

    if($counter%10 == 0)
    {
        // 10 seconds interval
    }
}
```

which covers all my needs ! :D

Don't worry PHP, I won't replace you with Node.js, you still my friend.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the websocket-framework you are using is too primitive to allow your server to do other useful things while waiting for connections from clients.  The only call to PHP's socket_select() function is hard-coded to a one second timeout, and it does nothing when the time runs out.  It really ought to allow a callback or an outside loop.

Look at the http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php manual page.  The last parameter is a timeout time.  socket_select() waits for incoming data on a socket or until the timeout time is up, which sounds like what you want to do, but the library has no provision for it.  Then look at how the library uses it in core/classes/SocketServer.php.

I'm assuming you call run() and then it just never returns to your calling code until it gets a message on the socket, which prevents you from doing anything.

Comment: In fact I'm not "using" this framework, I'm making it ahah :P But yes this timeout was my first hope of success, it enable me to run the loop every 1 seconds.. BUT, it works only when server receive no data because as soon as data is received, server execute the loop (before the 1 second timeout), therefore I can't rely on that :(

Comment: How about some branching code -- check if it's a timeout or a data received that caused socket_select() to finish, and then do the appropriate thing for your situation.

Comment: Then if my server receive data at an interval shorter than 1 second, the timeout will never cause the function to finish because this timeout is reset every time the function finish, so my method will never be executed :/

Comment: You'll probably have to keep track of the time yourself, and reset the timeout to a new calculated value, and/or just check the time and call your function yourself, as in your crazy idea #1.  PHP's socket library pretty much provides almost all of the same functionality as the C library and Unix kernel.  That is, there's not some clever hidden way that some other language can do something PHP can't, although it might do it better.  It is indeed a "hard" problem to avoid "drunken" time intervals in your event loop!

Comment: Yep I'm afraid it'll be the the best (but not perfect) solution... thanks for your time :)